# Unexpected performance hit in metal by changing uv coordinates

Tags: swift, rendering, texture-mapping, sampling, metal

Below is a simple vertex and fragment shader combo in `metal` that renders 64 identical 2D quads.

```
vertex VertexOut vertexMain(uint k [[ vertex_id ]],
                            uint ii [[instance_id]],
                            device float2* tex [[buffer(2)]],
                            device float2* position [[buffer(1)]],
                            device float* state [[buffer(0)]]){
    VertexOut output;
    int i = 4*ii+1;
    float2 pos = position[k];
    pos *= float2(state[i+2],state[i+3]);
    pos += float2(state[i],state[i+1]);
    pos.x *= state[0];
    output.position = float4(pos,0,1);
    output.tex = tex[k]*float2(du,dv);
    return output;
};
fragment float4 fragmentMain(VertexOut input [[stage_in]],
                             texture2d<float> texture [[texture(0)]],
                             sampler sam [[sampler(0)]] ){
    return texture.sample(sam, input.tex);
};
```

The sampler is using normalized coordinates so `du` and `dv` can range from 0 to 1 and control how large of a clip of the texture will be sampled starting at the lower left corner.

It seems I have a misunderstanding about how sampling works in metal. I would expect the computational cost to remain constant no matter what values `du` and `dv` hold. However as I increase `du` and `dv` to 1 the frame rate drops. I am not using any mipmapping nor am I changing the size of the quads that are rasterized on screen. The affect is more dramatic with linear filtering but happens with nearest filtering as well. It seems to me that since the number of pixels drawn to the screen is the same then the load on the GPU should not depend on `du` and `dv`. What am I missing?

EDIT: Here is my sampler and color attachment:

```
    let samplerDescriptor = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
    samplerDescriptor.normalizedCoordinates = true
    samplerDescriptor.minFilter = .linear
    samplerDescriptor.magFilter = .linear
    let sampler = device.makeSamplerState(descriptor: samplerDescriptor)

    let attachment = pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0]
            attachment?.isBlendingEnabled = true
            attachment?.sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
            attachment?.destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

Comment: Can you quantify how much of a frame rate drop you experience?

Comment: From 60 to 40 with linear sampling. From 60 to 50 with nearest sampling.

Comment: On which device and OS version?

Comment: iPad mini and iPad Pro 9.7 both running 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you increase `du` and `dv` your quads are displaying more of your texture. GPUs tend to have small-ish caches for texture data, and as you display more of your texture, you'll be discarding and refilling that cache more.

Thrashing the texture cache will use more memory bandwidth which is quite a limited resource, often texture memory bandwidth is not the bottleneck, but as your fragment shader is doing almost nothing other than texture fetches, it isn't a surprise that it's your bottleneck. Therefore, it isn't a surprise that altering your UVs has an effect on performance.

What is a surprise is that the framerate drops below 60 on these very powerful devices, when all you're doing is rendering 64 quads (iPad Pro in particular is a very powerful device). That said, maybe if all 64 quads were covering most of the screen, the framerate drop could be understandable.

To improve performance, you'd need to decrease the amount of texture data that needs to shovelled around by the GPU. Changing from 32-bit texture format (8888) to 16-bit (565/4444) or 4-bit (PVRTC compressed textures) would have a big impact.

The really big win is probably to enable mipmapping. Assuming that with high values of `du` and `dv`, you end up minimizing the texture, then using mipmapping will give a ***huge*** performance benefit, and as an added bonus your textures will look nicer too (it'll fix aliasing). Not a bad return for a 33% texture memory increase.

Comment: That is very interesting. I am using instance rendering, meaning all 64 quads are drawn together with a single texture binding and a single draw call. Would this caching issue still take place in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, texture caches are typically only a few KB, most textures are a few hundred KB. This is a good primer: https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-4/
It might be useful to understand your rendering scenario better - a screenshot perhaps. 64 small quads is nothing and something funny is going on if you can't hit 60fps. 64 quads that each cover the whole screen then I could understand the problem.

Comment: Each quad covers only 1% of the screen. I have added some more code describing my pipeline.

Comment: Sounds possible that the texture is very large compared to the on-screen coverage, so mipmapping would be a big win. But really I'm surprised that frame-rate is affected in such a simple scene even with a pathological texture sampling scenario. What is the texture format, width and height? and the approximate pixel size of the quads?

Comment: The raw image is 3900 by 1864. The rasterized quads are about 200 by 150. I am definitely going to start using mipmapping but obviously I would like to understand why this performance hit is taking place.

Comment: The texture file is RGBA